# Coinkite API Signature in PHP Not Matching

Tags: php, api, curl

There is no documentation on this or any samples to explore so Im stuck pulling my hair out. To connect to the Coinkite API I need to send three headers that creates a signature. I can recreate their test signature with the same results. So now when I actually send a signature to get json back I get a authentication error.

```
{ "help_msg": "Bad signature for endpoint: /v1/my/self", "message": "Unauthorized", "status": 401 }
```

Here is my code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
function sign($endpoint, $force_ts=false) 
{
$API_KEY = 'xxxx';
$API_SECRET = 'xxx';
if($force_ts) {
    $ts = $force_ts;
} else {
    $now = new DateTime();
    $ts = $now->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
}
$data = $endpoint . '|' . $ts;
$hm = hash_hmac('sha256', $data, $API_SECRET);
return array($hm, $ts);
}
$sign = (sign('/v1/my/self'));

$ch = curl_init('https://api.coinkite.com/v1/my/self');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('X-CK-Key: {$API_KEY}', 'X-CK-Sign: {$sign[0]}', 'X-CK- Timestamp: {$sign[1]}'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

The only thing I changed was the header sign and timestamp variables. $hm and $ts would give error for header sign and timestamp value being too short so I gave them the arrays from $sign to get it to work but am now creating a "bad signature."

How should the required items be sent so the signature authenticates?

Answer (score 1):

I ran your program, and the first time, it printed:

```
{
  "help_msg": "Header field is missing: X-CK-Timestamp",
  "message": "Unauthorized",
  "status": 401
}
```

So I noticed an extra space between X-CK- and Timestamp. Correcting that typo, it still fails though... so I added a line:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
```

.. and now it prints the headers it is sending. They have {} and $sign in them... not the values you want. That's as far as I got. Hope it helps!

PS: **You must revoke this key once you get it working!** The whole world knows it now that you've posted it here. Anyone can take your funds or at least mess with your account.

Comment: Thank you for noticing the typo also looking at that array again I didn't have double quotes so {} were passing as text.

I didn't have a way of seeing the headers so I added a variable in the HTTPHEADER setopt so I could echo them to see how they were coming out and the key wasn't showing up. Same reason why $hm and $ts also weren't working. I'm assuming because they are within the sign function. I set the key variable outside the function and now the key is being sent and everything works.